# Image map in a Confluence page

Tags: html, confluence

I can't get any of the links on the [image map in my Confluence page](http://michiganview.org:8090/display/MV/Copy+of+NAIP) to work correctly.

I added an HTML macro to insert an image map of Michigan counties, but the second map never seems to work. Some of the links don't appear, or they lead to incorrect places. For instance, you can't click on Emmet County or Cheboygan county, and when you click on Leelenau County, it gives you the download link for Houghton County instead.

It doesn't seem to matter what order I put the pictures in-- the second picture always gets messed up.

The code in the HTML macro is as follows (it's kind of long, sorry):

Top Map:

```html
<!-- Calculations based on an original image (width,height)=(1056,816) -->
<!-- Image Map Generated by http://www.image-map.net/ -->
<img src="http://i.imgur.com/gzeVBKT.png" usemap="#image-map" style="height: 386px; width: 500px;">
<map name="image-map">
            <area target="_blank" alt="" title="" href="http://per510a.mtri.org:8090/download/attachments/327710/NC_053_Gogebic_2005.zip?version=1&amp;modificationDate=1184690207149&amp;api=v2" coords="2,187,28,179,41,170,42,177,42,187,50,188,50,196,77,198,76,214,103,216,101,240,92,236,23,213,15,195,5,192,4,190,6,187" shape="poly">
            <area target="_blank" alt="" title="" href="http://per510a.mtri.org:8090/download/attachments/327710/NC_071_Iron_2005.zip?version=1&amp;modificationDate=1184703871067&amp;api=v2" coords="103,207,101,240,112,247,122,249,124,251,125,252,127,249,133,249,141,254,144,254,148,257,152,257,158,257,162,260,164,209" shape="poly">
            <area target="_blank" alt="" title="" href="http://per510a.mtri.org:8090/download/attachments/327710/NC_043_Dickinson_2005.zip?version=1&amp;modificationDate=1184681692044&amp;api=v2" coords="199,229,163,226,162,259,164,266,161,270,163,273,166,275,171,273,173,277,179,279,182,281,192,281,192,263,198,264" shape="poly">
            <area target="_blank" alt="" title="" href="http://per510a.mtri.org:8090/download/attachments/327710/NC_109_Menominee_2005.zip?version=1&amp;modificationDate=1184768892528&amp;api=v2" coords="198,255,215,255,216,265,218,265,218,299,223,301,218,313,199,340,197,346,188,336,195,320,192,315,188,320,179,320,179,312,183,307,182,298,188,296,182,290,186,286,181,281,192,281,193,265,197,263" shape="poly">
            <area target="_blank" alt="" title="" href="http://per510a.mtri.org:8090/download/attachments/327710/NC_041_Delta_2005.zip?version=1&amp;modificationDate=1213212779373&amp;api=v2" coords="222,301,230,287,239,284,237,275,241,271,243,263,245,263,248,266,245,269,243,285,252,281,256,275,258,268,262,269,268,269,271,265,276,267,272,275,268,277,262,287,268,295,270,287,274,282,278,279,281,277,281,265,279,264,279,237,225,237,225,254,216,256,217,262,219,263,219,297" shape="poly">
            <area target="_blank" alt="" title="" href="http://per510a.mtri.org:8090/download/attachments/327710/NC_041_Delta_2005.zip?version=1&amp;modificationDate=1213212779373&amp;api=v2" coords="256,304,258,310,269,301,270,295,266,298" shape="poly">
            <area target="_blank" alt="" title="" href="http://per510a.mtri.org:8090/download/attachments/327710/NC_153_Schoolcraft_2005.zip?version=1&amp;modificationDate=1193326104426&amp;api=v2" coords="281,277,288,275,290,262,298,259,305,259,311,258,319,262,321,257,323,257,322,202,288,202,287,219,270,219,270,237,279,237,279,264" shape="poly">
            <area target="_blank" alt="" title="" href="http://per510a.mtri.org:8090/download/attachments/327710/NC_097_1-2_Mackinac_2005.zip?version=1&amp;modificationDate=1213205186132&amp;api=v2" coords="323,258,326,257,337,259,347,244,358,245,372,249,382,252,389,256,389,260,394,264,402,269,405,268,404,260,405,256,407,250,411,251,415,251,417,255,423,257,429,260,432,259,438,257,439,245,430,246,429,237,375,238,376,228,322,229" shape="poly">
            <area target="_blank" alt="" title="" href="http://per510a.mtri.org:8090/download/attachments/327710/NC_097_2-2_Mackinac_2005.zip?version=1&amp;modificationDate=1213206473112&amp;api=v2" coords="410,265,411,271,418,277,419,281,429,281,430,275,420,273,415,271" shape="poly">
            <area target="_blank" alt="" title="" href="http://per510a.mtri.org:8090/download/attachments/327710/NC_033_1-2_Chippewa_2005.zip?version=1&amp;modificationDate=1214919819414&amp;api=v2" coords="367,228,367,178,375,175,380,176,389,175,381,182,382,198,380,201,385,205,390,204,394,207,397,208,408,204,413,205,422,208,426,202,430,202,435,202,439,198,442,198,446,198,447,201,445,211,446,220,448,230,455,236,456,241,458,242,460,247,463,245,465,257,456,257,447,254,439,254,439,246,430,245,429,238,376,238,376,228" shape="poly">
            <area target="_blank" alt="" title="" href="http://per510a.mtri.org:8090/download/attachments/327710/NC_033_2-2_Chippewa_2005.zip?version=1&amp;modificationDate=1214920174247&amp;api=v2" coords="467,240,472,241,482,240,486,241,497,253,491,259,484,260,480,257,472,258,464,257,463,247" shape="poly">
            <area target="_blank" alt="" title="" href="http://per510a.mtri.org:8090/download/attachments/327710/NC_095_Luce_2005.zip?version=1&amp;modificationDate=1184765303020&amp;api=v2" coords="323,204,322,185,346,186,367,178,366,229,322,229" shape="poly">
            <area target="_blank" alt="" title="" href="http://per510a.mtri.org:8090/download/attachments/327710/NC_003_Alger_2005.zip?version=2&amp;modificationDate=1183046325771&amp;api=v2" coords="234,202,245,198,247,205,250,207,254,209,257,207,262,205,264,207,264,198,268,196,269,198,268,204,270,205,266,208,268,211,281,198,285,197,304,187,323,185,323,202,288,202,287,220,269,220,269,238,235,237" shape="poly">
            <area target="_blank" alt="" title="" href="http://per510a.mtri.org:8090/download/attachments/327710/NC_103_1-2_Marquette_2005.zip?version=1&amp;modificationDate=1213199349104&amp;api=v2" coords="171,159,181,159,192,165,198,170,202,172,204,179,211,189,217,195,217,200,225,205,235,202,236,237,225,237,224,254,199,254,200,227,164,227,165,183,173,182,175,175,170,173" shape="poly">
            <area target="_blank" alt="" title="" href="http://per510a.mtri.org:8090/download/attachments/327710/NC_013_Baraga_2005.zip?version=1&amp;modificationDate=1183127429111&amp;api=v2" coords="135,155,143,155,139,166,141,168,140,175,145,168,145,162,149,162,166,153,153,168,161,160,171,159,169,173,173,175,174,182,164,183,164,209,125,208,126,164,135,164" shape="poly">
            <area target="_blank" alt="" title="" href="http://per510a.mtri.org:8090/download/attachments/327710/NC_061_Houghton_2005.zip?version=1&amp;modificationDate=1184697829978&amp;api=v2" coords="103,207,125,209,125,164,135,164,135,155,141,154,147,149,150,141,154,138,158,135,158,129,154,129,153,120,139,120,125,128,120,133,115,137,110,139,108,147,108,173,112,173,112,181,104,181" shape="poly">
            <area target="_blank" alt="" title="" href="http://per510a.mtri.org:8090/download/attachments/327710/NC_131_Ontonagon_2005.zip?version=1&amp;modificationDate=1184159290800&amp;api=v2" coords="42,170,48,163,58,164,68,163,72,163,88,156,93,149,102,149,108,145,108,173,112,173,112,181,103,181,103,216,77,214,77,198,50,196,50,188,43,188" shape="poly">
            <area target="_blank" alt="" title="" href="http://per510a.mtri.org:8090/download/attachments/327710/NC_083_Keweenaw_2005.zip?version=1&amp;modificationDate=1184763057858&amp;api=v2" coords="140,120,148,110,161,105,171,101,184,103,189,103,194,106,194,109,187,111,179,110,177,113,179,116,170,122,163,128,158,130,153,129,154,120" shape="poly">
            <area target="_blank" alt="" title="" href="http://per510a.mtri.org:8090/download/attachments/327710/NC_083_Keweenaw_2005.zip?version=1&amp;modificationDate=1184763057858&amp;api=v2" coords="89,58,97,64,112,57,106,56,119,49,124,51,137,42,137,38,150,28,139,30,115,44,96,51" shape="poly">
        </map>
```

Bottom Map [truncated for clarity]:

```html
<!-- Calculations based on an original image (width,height)=(816,1056) -->
<img src="http://imgur.com/AtlRmWN.png" usemap="#image-map" align="center" style="height: 647px; width: 500px;">
<map name="image-map">
        <area target="_blank" alt="" title="" href="http://per510a.mtri.org:8090/download/attachments/327710/NC_021_Berrien_2005.zip?version=1&amp;modificationDate=1183129121425&amp;api=v2" coords="20,606,83,607,83,537,69,537,56,556,50,569,47,578,39,591,34,595" shape="poly">
        <area target="_blank" alt="" title="" href="http://per510a.mtri.org:8090/download/attachments/327710/NC_027_Cass_2005.zip?version=1&amp;modificationDate=1183140086748&amp;api=v2" coords="84,563,133,563,133,601,129,606,82,606" shape="poly">
        <area target="_blank" alt="" title="" href="http://per510a.mtri.org:8090/download/attachments/327710/NC_149_StJoseph_2005.zip?version=1&amp;modificationDate=1193324420641&amp;api=v2" coords="133,562,182,562,183,606,129,606,133,601" shape="poly">
        <area target="_blank" alt="" title="" href="http://per510a.mtri.org:8090/download/attachments/327710/NC_023_Branch_2005.zip?version=1&amp;modificationDate=1183129060066&amp;api=v2" coords="182,562,231,562,233,604,226,606,182,607" shape="poly">
        <area target="_blank" alt="" title="" href="http://per510a.mtri.org:8090/download/attachments/327710/NC_059_Hillsdale_2005.zip?version=1&amp;modificationDate=1184696660019&amp;api=v2" coords="231,562,281,561,283,612,236,614" shape="poly">
        <area target="_blank" alt="" title="" href="http://per510a.mtri.org:8090/download/attachments/327710/NC_091_Lenawee_2005.zip?version=1&amp;modificationDate=1184764411421&amp;api=v2" coords="281,560,344,558,346,608,282,612" shape="poly">
        <area target="_blank" alt="" title="" href="http://per510a.mtri.org:8090/download/attachments/327710/NC_115_Monroe_2005.zip?version=1&amp;modificationDate=1184770066780&amp;api=v2" coords="343,557,393,555,405,563,401,569,398,575,393,576,391,583,387,588,382,593,378,598,382,602,378,607,346,610" shape="poly">
        <area target="_blank" alt="" title="" href="http://per510a.mtri.org:8090/download/attachments/327710/NC_159_VanBuren_2005.zip?version=1&amp;modificationDate=1193326191060&amp;api=v2" coords="69,537,78,513,132,513,131,563,84,561,85,537" shape="poly">
        <area target="_blank" alt="" title="" href="http://per510a.mtri.org:8090/download/attachments/327710/NC_077_Kalamazoo_2005.zip?version=1&amp;modificationDate=1184761923735&amp;api=v2" coords="131,512,181,561" shape="rect">
        <area target="_blank" alt="" title="" href="http://per510a.mtri.org:8090/download/attachments/327710/NC_025_Calhoun_2005.zip?version=1&amp;modificationDate=1183130669353&amp;api=v2" coords="182,513,243,512,244,561,182,561" shape="poly">
        <area target="_blank" alt="" title="" href="http://per510a.mtri.org:8090/download/attachments/327710/NC_075_Jackson_2005.zip?version=1&amp;modificationDate=1184704954903&amp;api=v2" coords="243,512,305,509,305,559,244,561,243,531" shape="poly">
        <area target="_blank" alt="" title="" href="http://per510a.mtri.org:8090/download/attachments/327710/NC_161_Washtenaw_2005.zip?version=1&amp;modificationDate=1193323502252&amp;api=v2" coords="305,510,366,507,368,556,306,559" shape="poly">
        <area target="_blank" alt="" title="" href="http://per510a.mtri.org:8090/download/attachments/327710/NC_163_Wayne_2005.zip?version=1&amp;modificationDate=1193325443330&amp;api=v2" coords="366,507,438,502,437,510,432,513,432,517,417,521,412,532,411,540,413,551,410,563,403,563,393,554,368,556" shape="poly">
        <area target="_blank" alt="" title="" href="http://per510a.mtri.org:8090/download/attachments/327710/NC_005_Allegan_2005.zip?version=1&amp;modificationDate=1183125502405&amp;api=v2" coords="85,463,155,463,155,512,79,512,83,485" shape="poly">
        <area target="_blank" alt="" title="" href="http://per510a.mtri.org:8090/download/attachments/327710/NC_015_Barry_2005.zip?version=1&amp;modificationDate=1183127339197&amp;api=v2" coords="155,463,204,461,205,512,155,512" shape="poly">
        <area target="_blank" alt="" title="" href="http://per510a.mtri.org:8090/download/attachments/327710/NC_045_Eaton_2005.zip?version=1&amp;modificationDate=1184683240186&amp;api=v2" coords="254,461,205,512" shape="rect">
        <area target="_blank" alt="" title="" href="http://per510a.mtri.org:8090/download/attachments/327710/NC_065_Ingham_2005.zip?version=1&amp;modificationDate=1184701802012&amp;api=v2" coords="253,461,302,461,303,510,254,512" shape="poly">
        <area target="_blank" alt="" title="" href="http://per510a.mtri.org:8090/download/attachments/327710/NC_093_Livingston_2005.zip?version=1&amp;modificationDate=1184765387667&amp;api=v2" coords="302,458,349,458,354,508,303,510" shape="poly">
        <area target="_blank" alt="" title="" href="http://per510a.mtri.org:8090/download/attachments/327710/NC_125_Oakland_2005.zip?version=1&amp;modificationDate=1184162634049&amp;api=v2" coords="NaN" shape="poly">
        <area target="_blank" alt="" title="" href="http://per510a.mtri.org:8090/download/attachments/327710/NC_125_Oakland_2005.zip?version=1&amp;modificationDate=1184162634049&amp;api=v2" coords="349,444,411,441,416,504,354,507" shape="poly">
        <area target="_blank" alt="" title="" href="http://per510a.mtri.org:8090/download/attachments/327710/NC_099_Macomb_2005.zip?version=1&amp;modificationDate=1184766137004&amp;api=v2" coords="411,441,449,438,452,466,447,471,442,474,442,479,447,481,445,485,439,486,437,494,437,501,416,503" shape="poly">
        <area target="_blank" alt="" title="" href="http://per510a.mtri.org:8090/download/attachments/327710/NC_147_StClair_2005.zip?version=1&amp;modificationDate=1193324390595&amp;api=v2" coords="423,439,422,403,474,398,482,422,482,427,479,432,477,441,476,447,479,456,474,469,475,474,466,486,456,488,452,479,461,469,454,467,448,469,452,462,449,437" shape="poly">
        <area target="_blank" alt="" title="" href="http://per510a.mtri.org:8090/download/attachments/327710/NC_087_Lapeer_2005.zip?version=1&amp;modificationDate=1184763761288&amp;api=v2" coords="383,390,383,381,406,378,407,383,420,384,423,439,374,442,372,393" shape="poly">
        <area target="_blank" alt="" title="" href="http://per510a.mtri.org:8090/download/attachments/327710/NC_049_Genesee_2005.zip?version=1&amp;modificationDate=1184689045665&amp;api=v2" coords="324,459,324,396,372,394,374,443,350,444,349,458" shape="poly">
        <area target="_blank" alt="" title="" href="http://per510a.mtri.org:8090/download/attachments/327710/NC_155_Shiawassee_2005.zip?version=1&amp;modificationDate=1193326121795&amp;api=v2" coords="278,410,323,408,324,457,300,460,280,460" shape="poly">
        <area target="_blank" alt="" title="" href="http://per510a.mtri.org:8090/download/attachments/327710/NC_037_Clinton_2005.zip?version=1&amp;modificationDate=1184679969602&amp;api=v2" coords="229,413,278,411,280,461,230,460" shape="poly">
        <area target="_blank" alt="" title="" href="http://per510a.mtri.org:8090/download/attachments/327710/NC_067_Ionia_2005.zip?version=1&amp;modificationDate=1184702294280&amp;api=v2" coords="178,412,229,412,229,462,180,462" shape="poly">
        <area target="_blank" alt="" title="" href="http://per510a.mtri.org:8090/download/attachments/327710/NC_081_Kent_2005.zip?version=1&amp;modificationDate=1184762607151&amp;api=v2" coords="129,388,180,462" shape="rect">
        <area target="_blank" alt="" title="" href="http://per510a.mtri.org:8090/download/attachments/327710/NC_39_Ottawa_2005.zip?version=1&amp;modificationDate=1193323806964&amp;api=v2" coords="84,462,129,463,128,401,116,401,116,414,78,413,84,432" shape="poly">
        <area target="_blank" alt="" title="" href="http://per510a.mtri.org:8090/download/attachments/327710/NC_121_Muskegon_2005.zip?version=1&amp;modificationDate=1184771611854&amp;api=v2" coords="104,363,104,387,128,388,128,400,116,400,116,413,79,412,67,390,64,379,59,362" shape="poly">
        <area target="_blank" alt="" title="" href="http://per510a.mtri.org:8090/download/attachments/327710/NC_017_Bay_2005.zip?version=1&amp;modificationDate=1183128471438&amp;api=v2" coords="346,358,346,341,327,333,319,319,323,298,309,296,308,286,295,285,298,347,311,346,311,354,331,352,333,358" shape="poly">
        <area target="_blank" alt="" title="" href="http://per510a.mtri.org:8090/download/attachments/327710/NC_111_Midland_2005.zip?version=1&amp;modificationDate=1184769290360&amp;api=v2" coords="298,359,276,359,274,363,252,361,250,312,273,312,273,309,296,309" shape="poly">
        <area target="_blank" alt="" title="" href="http://per510a.mtri.org:8090/download/attachments/327710/NC_073_Isabella_2005.zip?version=1&amp;modificationDate=1184704397132&amp;api=v2" coords="252,361,201,363,200,313,249,312" shape="poly">
        <area target="_blank" alt="" title="" href="http://per510a.mtri.org:8090/download/attachments/327710/NC_107_Mecosta_2005.zip?version=1&amp;modificationDate=1184767659495&amp;api=v2" coords="152,313,201,363" shape="rect">
        <area target="_blank" alt="" title="" href="http://per510a.mtri.org:8090/download/attachments/327710/NC_011_Arenac_2005.zip?version=1&amp;modificationDate=1183126177793&amp;api=v2" coords="321,297,330,286,347,285,347,276,354,276,357,268,357,260,295,260,297,285,309,285,309,297" shape="poly">
        <area target="_blank" alt="" title="" href="http://per510a.mtri.org:8090/download/attachments/327710/NC_051_Gladwin_2005.zip?version=1&amp;modificationDate=1184689414363&amp;api=v2" coords="250,312,250,262,296,263,296,309,275,309,273,311" shape="poly">
        <area target="_blank" alt="" title="" href="http://per510a.mtri.org:8090/download/attachments/327710/NC_035_Clare_2005.zip?version=1&amp;modificationDate=1184680016025&amp;api=v2" coords="201,262,251,313" shape="rect">
        <area target="_blank" alt="" title="" href="http://per510a.mtri.org:8090/download/attachments/327710/NC_133_Osceola_2005.zip?version=1&amp;modificationDate=1183752102902&amp;api=v2" coords="152,263,200,313" shape="rect">
        <area target="_blank" alt="" title="" href="http://per510a.mtri.org:8090/download/attachments/327710/NC_085_Lake_2005.zip?version=1&amp;modificationDate=1184763431902&amp;api=v2" coords="102,263,152,263,151,314,104,314" shape="poly">
        <area target="_blank" alt="" title="" href="http://per510a.mtri.org:8090/download/attachments/327710/NC_105_Mason_2005.zip?version=1&amp;modificationDate=1184767703167&amp;api=v2" coords="67,261,102,263,103,312,63,313,60,292,53,282,56,276,63,270" shape="poly">
        <area target="_blank" alt="" title="" href="http://per510a.mtri.org:8090/download/attachments/327710/NC_101_Manistee_2005.zip?version=1&amp;modificationDate=1184766948514&amp;api=v2" coords="67,260,80,237,80,224,83,213,127,214,124,263,99,263" shape="poly">
        <area target="_blank" alt="" title="" href="http://per510a.mtri.org:8090/download/attachments/327710/NC_165_Wexford_2005.zip?version=1&amp;modificationDate=1193324266716&amp;api=v2" coords="126,214,175,214,175,263,125,263" shape="poly">
        <area target="_blank" alt="" title="" href="http://per510a.mtri.org:8090/download/attachments/327710/NC_113_Missaukee_2005.zip?version=1&amp;modificationDate=1184770128601&amp;api=v2" coords="175,213,225,213,225,263,176,263" shape="poly">
        <area target="_blank" alt="" title="" href="http://per510a.mtri.org:8090/download/attachments/327710/NC_143_Roscommon_2005.zip?version=1&amp;modificationDate=1193324322727&amp;api=v2" coords="225,212,273,213,275,263,225,263" shape="poly">
        <area target="_blank" alt="" title="" href="http://per510a.mtri.org:8090/download/attachments/327710/NC_129_Ogemaw_2005.zip?version=1&amp;modificationDate=1184159831571&amp;api=v2" coords="274,213,324,211,324,260,275,263" shape="poly">
        <area target="_blank" alt="" title="" href="http://per510a.mtri.org:8090/download/attachments/327710/NC_069_Iosco_2005.zip?version=1&amp;modificationDate=1184702848499&amp;api=v2" coords="323,211,381,209,380,234,372,239,369,246,365,243,360,248,358,260,324,261" shape="poly">
        <area target="_blank" alt="" title="" href="http://per510a.mtri.org:8090/download/attachments/327710/NC_001_Alcona_2005.zip?version=2&amp;modificationDate=1182876202960&amp;api=v2" coords="324,212,322,162,379,159,381,165,382,177,384,180,383,192,381,199,381,210" shape="poly">
        <area target="_blank" alt="" title="" href="http://per510a.mtri.org:8090/download/attachments/327710/NC_017_Bay_2005.zip?version=1&amp;modificationDate=1183128471438&amp;api=v2" coords="346,358,346,341,327,333,319,319,323,298,309,296,308,286,295,285,298,347,311,346,311,354,331,352,333,358" shape="poly">
        <area target="_blank" alt="" title="" href="http://per510a.mtri.org:8090/download/attachments/327710/NC_111_Midland_2005.zip?version=1&amp;modificationDate=1184769290360&amp;api=v2" coords="298,359,276,359,274,363,252,361,250,312,273,312,273,309,296,309" shape="poly">
        <area target="_blank" alt="" title="" href="http://per510a.mtri.org:8090/download/attachments/327710/NC_073_Isabella_2005.zip?version=1&amp;modificationDate=1184704397132&amp;api=v2" coords="252,361,201,363,200,313,249,312" shape="poly">
        <area target="_blank" alt="" title="" href="http://per510a.mtri.org:8090/download/attachments/327710/NC_107_Mecosta_2005.zip?version=1&amp;modificationDate=1184767659495&amp;api=v2" coords="152,313,201,363" shape="rect">
        <area target="_blank" alt="" title="" href="http://per510a.mtri.org:8090/download/attachments/327710/NC_011_Arenac_2005.zip?version=1&amp;modificationDate=1183126177793&amp;api=v2" coords="321,297,330,286,347,285,347,276,354,276,357,268,357,260,295,260,297,285,309,285,309,297" shape="poly">
        <area target="_blank" alt="" title="" href="http://per510a.mtri.org:8090/download/attachments/327710/NC_051_Gladwin_2005.zip?version=1&amp;modificationDate=1184689414363&amp;api=v2" coords="250,312,250,262,296,263,296,309,275,309,273,311" shape="poly">
        <area target="_blank" alt="" title="" href="http://per510a.mtri.org:8090/download/attachments/327710/NC_035_Clare_2005.zip?version=1&amp;modificationDate=1184680016025&amp;api=v2" coords="201,262,251,313" shape="rect">
        <area target="_blank" alt="" title="" href="http://per510a.mtri.org:8090/download/attachments/327710/NC_133_Osceola_2005.zip?version=1&amp;modificationDate=1183752102902&amp;api=v2" coords="152,263,200,313" shape="rect">
        <area target="_blank" alt="" title="" href="http://per510a.mtri.org:8090/download/attachments/327710/NC_085_Lake_2005.zip?version=1&amp;modificationDate=1184763431902&amp;api=v2" coords="102,263,152,263,151,314,104,314" shape="poly">
        <area target="_blank" alt="" title="" href="http://per510a.mtri.org:8090/download/attachments/327710/NC_105_Mason_2005.zip?version=1&amp;modificationDate=1184767703167&amp;api=v2" coords="67,261,102,263,103,312,63,313,60,292,53,282,56,276,63,270" shape="poly">
        <area target="_blank" alt="" title="" href="http://per510a.mtri.org:8090/download/attachments/327710/NC_101_Manistee_2005.zip?version=1&amp;modificationDate=1184766948514&amp;api=v2" coords="67,260,80,237,80,224,83,213,127,214,124,263,99,263" shape="poly">
        <area target="_blank" alt="" title="" href="http://per510a.mtri.org:8090/download/attachments/327710/NC_165_Wexford_2005.zip?version=1&amp;modificationDate=1193324266716&amp;api=v2" coords="126,214,175,214,175,263,125,263" shape="poly">
        <area target="_blank" alt="" title="" href="http://per510a.mtri.org:8090/download/attachments/327710/NC_113_Missaukee_2005.zip?version=1&amp;modificationDate=1184770128601&amp;api=v2" coords="175,213,225,213,225,263,176,263" shape="poly">
        <area target="_blank" alt="" title="" href="http://per510a.mtri.org:8090/download/attachments/327710/NC_143_Roscommon_2005.zip?version=1&amp;modificationDate=1193324322727&amp;api=v2" coords="225,212,273,213,275,263,225,263" shape="poly">
        <area target="_blank" alt="" title="" href="http://per510a.mtri.org:8090/download/attachments/327710/NC_129_Ogemaw_2005.zip?version=1&amp;modificationDate=1184159831571&amp;api=v2" coords="274,213,324,211,324,260,275,263" shape="poly">
        <area target="_blank" alt="" title="" href="http://per510a.mtri.org:8090/download/attachments/327710/NC_069_Iosco_2005.zip?version=1&amp;modificationDate=1184702848499&amp;api=v2" coords="323,211,381,209,380,234,372,239,369,246,365,243,360,248,358,260,324,261" shape="poly">
        <area target="_blank" alt="" title="" href="http://per510a.mtri.org:8090/download/attachments/327710/NC_001_Alcona_2005.zip?version=2&amp;modificationDate=1182876202960&amp;api=v2" coords="324,212,322,162,379,159,381,165,382,177,384,180,383,192,381,199,381,210" shape="poly">
        <area target="_blank" alt="" title="" href="http://per510a.mtri.org:8090/download/attachments/327710/NC_151_Sanilac_2005.zip?version=1&amp;modificationDate=1193326059865&amp;api=v2" coords="410,377,409,384,421,383,421,403,473,398,466,362,458,324,406,328,409,358" shape="poly">
        <area target="_blank" alt="" title="" href="http://per510a.mtri.org:8090/download/attachments/327710/NC_157_Tuscola_2005.zip?version=1&amp;modificationDate=1193326148817&amp;api=v2" coords="347,395,384,393,382,379,409,377,406,328,369,330,368,324,361,326,352,339,345,344" shape="poly">
    [...]
    </map>
```

Comment: You need to use a different name for the second image, because the connection between the image and the map is made via that ...

Comment: That solved it! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

> It doesn't seem to matter what order I put the pictures in-- the second picture always gets messed up.

That's because you used the same name for both images.

You need to use a different name for the second image, because the connection between the image and the map is made via that name.